# how to enable cors domain url angular js php application

Tags: php, angularjs

How we can solve by using Proxypass and proxyrevespass is the correct way or i can use the any other method like Is it Angular $http.defaults.useXDomain really neccessary in CORS? let me check I am using bellow code

on confuguration file

```
var configuration = {
 baseServiceAddress:'/api'

}
```

on service file:

```
services.factory('searchService', function($http, cfg, $log) {
return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                url: baseServiceAddress+'somemethod',
                data: {}
            }).success(function(res) {
                //do some code here
         });
}
};
```

when i am working with this code its search for 
`192.168.10.4/api/somemethod`  with 404 on Chrome browse console.

inorder to resolve i want to use Apache revese proxy like bellow is good method? is not working for me

`/api  yahoo.com/api/somemethod`

i am getting 500 error.

Comment: i added revese proxy like this

Comment: ProxyPass /api  http://192.168.10.59:8080/test2
ProxyPassReverse /api  http://192.168.10.59:8080/test2